# Onchange pop out error javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I try to auto calculate the input without any button. I try to do it with javascript onchange function.However, javascript keep pop out the error and I do not know how to solve it.

This is the error : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

below is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script>
function jsfunction()
{
var x=document.getElementById("qty1");
var y =document.getElementById("price1");
var z =document.getElementById("total1");


   alert("You entered: " + y.value);


}
</script>

<body>
<?php
$item=array("A"=>"10","B"=>"11","C"=>"12","D"=>"13");
$var=1;
$total=0;
$gtotal=0;

?>
<table border=1 width='600'
<tr>
<th>No</th>
<th>item</th>
<th>Check</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Qty</th>
<th>Total</th>
</tr>";
<?php
foreach($item as $myItem=>$pricetag){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$var."</td>";
echo "<td>".$myItem."</td>";
$price = "price". $var;
$qty = "qty". $var;
$total = "total". $var;
?>

<td><input type="checkbox" id="chkbox" name="chkbox"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name=<?php $price ?> id=<?php $price ?>  size =1/><?php  echo $price ?> </td>
<td><input type="text" onchange="jsfunction() name=<?php $qty ?> id=<?php $qty ?> size =1/><?php echo $qty ?></td>
<td><input type="text" name=<?php $total ?> id=<?php $total ?> size =1/></td>


<?php
$var++;
}?>


</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are a few problems:

1. You never have the closing `>` of the `<table>` tag:

   `<table border=1 width='600'` => `<table border=1 width='600'>`
2. You have a random `";` when the code is not even PHP nor JavaScript:

   ```
   <th>Total</th>
   </tr>";
   ```
3. You are using the PHP tag as an echo tag:

   `<?php $price ?>` => `<?php echo $price ?>`
4. You never close the double quotes when calling your JavaScript function:

   `onchange="jsfunction()` => `onchange="jsfunction()"`
5. **EDIT**:

   If your `name` property is NULL, it may cause problems because the `id` will be set to the name, so you should wrap the name in quotes (Just to be safe you should probably do it with everything including `id`, `size`, `name`, etc.):

   `name=<?php $price ?>` => `name="<?php $price ?>"`

Comment: After I change all the errors, it pop this message to me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Comment: Oh ya, I forgot to change the <?php echo $price ?> . Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Among other things, this line has a JavaScript error:

```
<td><input type="text" onchange="jsfunction() name=<?php $qty ?> id=<?php $qty ?> size =1/><?php echo $qty ?></td>
```

It should probably be:

```
<td><input type="text" onchange="jsfunction()" name="<?php echo $qty; ?>" id="<?php echo $qty; ?>" size="1" /><?php echo $qty; ?></td>
```

You must use the `echo` function to print out a PHP variable to the HTML.

Also, throughout your HTML form, don't forget to wrap all the input parameter values in quotation marks (" ").

Comment: after i change it, it still pop out the error. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `$price`?  You are getting element's by their id, e.g. price1, but if `$price` is not equal to the string 'price1' it will fail to get an element by that id and your javascript will be calling into a null value.

Comment: but the $price = price1 , i just want to getelementid to retrieve the value